# Adding extra Literal Character 

Tags: c#, string, literals

I need to assign a string with `"doTask.ex /select:"" + cmd + "param:"`

I want a extra qoute after /select: , what escape characeter i have to use or how to do this

```
String cmd = "doTask.ex /select:"" + cmd + "param:";
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
String cmd = "doTask.ex /select:\"" + cmd + "param:";
```

Answer (score 2):

In a regular string you use a backslash as escape character:

```
String cmd = "doTask.ex /select:\"" + cmd + "param:";
```

In a @ delimited string you use double quotation marks:

```
String cmd = @"doTask.ex /select:""" + cmd + "param:";
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape Character for `"` is `\"`

```
String cmd = "doTask.ex /select:\"" + cmd + "param:";
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely googling this is faster than asking on so?! Escape characters with \. Like this:

```
String cmd = "doTask.ex /select:\"" + cmd + "param:";
```